# Radius of convergence of a series which diverges when every term is made positive

Tags: analysis, power-series

$\{\,a_n\mid n \ge 1\,\}$  be sequence of real numbers. 
Partial sum of $a_n$ forms a convergent series. 
Partial sum of absolute value of $a_n$ forms a divergent series. 
Let radius of convergence of power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$
be $R$.
Then is $R$ infinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: it's $R=1$. Power series are absolutely convergent for each $\lvert x\rvert< R$, so $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\lvert a_n\rvert=\infty$ implies $R\le1$. Since power series are divergent for $\lvert x\rvert >R$ and $\sum_{n= 1}\limits^\infty a_n$ converges, it must also be $R\ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The radius of convergence depends only on the absolute values of the coeffiicients, as seen from example from the formula
$$ \frac 1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}.$$
In particular, if $R>1$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|$ converges. We are given that the latter isnot the case, hence $R\le 1$.